# How to delete/remove the repository from sesame using Java API

Tags: java, rdf, sesame

I have multiple turtle files. I am uploading those turtle(ttl) files to sesame memory store using **LocalRepositoryManager** and **SailrRepository**

Code for uploading files to sesame memory store

Initialization of LocalRepositoryManager:

```
String dataDir = "D:\\SesameStorage\\data\\"
LocalRepositoryManager localManager = new LocalRepositoryManager(new File(dataDir));
localManager.initialize();
```

Adding repository to LocalRepositoryManager :

```
String repositoryName = "data.ttl";

RepositoryConfig repConfig = new RepositoryConfig(repositoryName);
SailRepositoryConfig config = new SailRepositoryConfig(new MemoryStoreConfig());
repConfig.setRepositoryImplConfig(config);
manager.addRepositoryConfig(repConfig);
```

Getting the repository object :

```
Repository repository = manager.getRepository(repositoryName);
repository.initialize();
```

Getting repository Connection to add ttl file to it.

```
File f = new File("D:\\SesameStorage\\data.ttl");
String fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();

RepositoryConnection con = repository.getConnection();
con.add(f, "file://" + fileName, RDFFormat.forFileName(fileName));
```

I am successfully adding that data.ttl file to sesame memory store.

But when I remove that repository from sesame server and try to delete the data.ttl file it gives me following exception :

**"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."**

Code for removing repository is:

```
RepositoryConnection connection = manager.getRepository(repositoryName).getConnection();
if (connection != null) {
    connection.clear();
    connection.close();
    manager.removeRepository(repositoryName);

    File srcFile = new File("D:\\SesameStorage\\"+ repositoryName);
    if (srcFile.exists()) {
        srcFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Because of this I am not able to release or delete the turtle file.

Is there anything I've done wrong?

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with Sesame as far as I can tell: you are getting this when invoking `srcFile.delete`, which is a Java file system IO operation. Presumably, you still have another open reference to that same file somewhere in your code, which causes this error. Can you provide a complete, executable code example (not individual snippets) that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks Jeen, actually I am adding this file to repository connection as it is   con.add(f, "file://" + fileName, RDFFormat.forFileName(fileName)); Instead of doing this I have used StringReader and passed it to the connection object and its working fine for me. Thanks for your valuable time.